# change margin-right value of an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

I have created a simple `<ul>` list in HTML and assigned different values of margin-right to each of the `<li>'s` using CSS ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjkLquge/2/)). This is the HTML mark-up of it:

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
     display: inline-block;
}

ul li:first-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 30px;
}

ul li:nth-child(4) {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

The question which I have in my mind is that would it be possible to replace the margin-right value of the first-child `<li>` with that of the second-child `<li>` utilizing the following jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery('ul li:first-child').css('margin-right', '');
```

For example, the first-child `<li>` has a margin-right value of 10px and the second-child `<li>` has a margin-right value of 20px therefore the jQuery should replace the margin-right value of the first-child `<li>` to 20px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly there, you just never asked the second child what its `margin-right` was:

```
jQuery('ul li:first-child').css('margin-right', jQuery('ul li:first-child').next().css('margin-right'));
```

Or more efficiently (and clearly):

```
var first = jQuery('ul li:first-child');
first.css('margin-right', first.next().css('margin-right'));
```

Or even more clearly:

```
var first = jQuery('ul li:first-child');
var marginRight = first.next().css('margin-right');
first.css('margin-right', marginRight);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjkLquge/6/) - Note that one of the things I had to change in the fiddle was that you had the "No wrap - in head" option chosen, which means that the JavaScript code runs before the elements exist. I changed it to "No wrap - in body" so the script is at the end of the body, so all the elements exist.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

p.s. I will be able to accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: I am facing a little problem. If the margin-right values are in percentages, the jQuery assigns the value in pixels. Is there any way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: @FahadHasan: Not as far as I'm aware, no; the various means of getting this information give it to you in pixels on most browsers. You'd have to traverse the `styleSheets` array, looking for rules that match the `li`, and then extracting the relevant style value from the rule. Non-trivial, to put it mildly.